# Display get_post_meta if contains value

Tags: post-meta

Am struggling to get the below to work.

I just want to display the `get_post_meta` 'title_override_text' if it contains any value otherwise just display the standard title (already catered for in functions.php).

```
<?php $h1override = get_post_meta($id, "title_override_text", true); ?>
<?php if (!empty($h1override)) { ?>
    <h1><span><?php title_text(); ?></span></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1><span><?php title_override_text(); ?></span></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

It correctly displays 'title_override_text' if there is a value but when the field is empty, it doesn't display anything at all (i.e not 'title_text').

How can I display 'title_override_text' if it contains any value (it is a text field)?

Is there a better way of doing this like using (for example):-

```
if(get_post_meta($id, "page_title_override_text", true) == ""
```

Comment: Shurely it should be `if (empty($h1override))` rather than `if (!empty...`?

Comment: @bonger I tried that as well but it had no effect. I actually managed to achieve what I was trying to do a better way - will post it as an answer as soon as I can...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually managed to achieve what I needed to do in the end by using the below:-

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($id, "h1_title_override", true) !== '') { ?>
    <h1><?php title_override_text(); ?></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1><?php title_text(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

With the necessary functions in place of course...